# Using NGINX on-prem as LB for kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I already had NGINX handling my reverse-proxy and load balancing for bare-metals and VMs, wonder if I can use the same instance for my Kubernetes cluster exposing services in load-balancer mode. If so, could I use it for both L4 and L7?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use it as type [`LoadBalancer`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/#loadbalancer) because there's no [`cloud-provider`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/cloud-providers/) API to handle an external Nginx instance.  You can do a couple of things I can think of:

1. Create Kubernetes Service exposed on a [`NodePort`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/#nodeport). So your architecture will look like this:

   ```
   External NGINX -> Kubernetes NodePort Service -> Pods
   ```
2. Create a Kubernetes [Ingress managed](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) by an ingress controller. The most popular happens to be [Nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/). So your architecture will look something like this:

   ```
   External NGINX -> Kubernetes Service (has to be NodePort) -> Ingress (NGINX) -> Backend Service -> Pods
   ```